# Changing file name on upload using id in Django ImageField

Tags: django, imagefield

In this model, I want to change the name of the file uploaded in ImageField

```
class Product(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

To change the name of image I'm using this function

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = '%s.%s' % (instance.id, ext)

    return os.path.join('products', filename)
```

but the name of my image is None, if I use other fields like 'name', it works. What should I do to change the name with id? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The instance's `id` is not yet created, because the `upload_to` function is called *before* the new object is first written to the database.

> In most cases, this object will not have been saved to the database yet, so if it uses the default AutoField, *it might not yet have a value for its primary key field.*

Emphasis from the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

Two alternatives:

Use a `uuid.uuid4()` value, its easy to create and as unique as the `pk`.

Another suggestion, if you care about search engines and SEO, use a `slugify(instance.name)` so that your images can be easier found in the image search of search engines.

Comment: thanks for suggestions, I will try them. thanks again.